# How to recursively call a method after every given batch in java?

Tags: java

I want to do some big operation, say for example I want to do massive update for ~ 15000 times. I am facing OOM (Out of Memory) If I do it in single shot. I am planning to break the work in multiple bathes. For example, I want to take first 500 items and complete the work Then sleep for 2 mins and then process the next upcoming items.

```
    int count = 0;
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        
     item.setValue("xxx ", xxx);
     session.save();
     count ++;
        for(int i = 0; i< 500; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i< 1000; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i< 1500; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
        }
        ....
      }
                
    }
```

The for loop is keep increasing in this approach. Is there any available API or better option to manage use case like this?

Comment: You shouldn't have to wait two minutes. You should only have to make sure that the memory you used is available for garbage collection. If it isn't, then waiting two minutes is not going to help.

Comment: GC might run and clear the memory

Answer (score 1):

Spring Batch is capable of doing that like this.

```
public void recursive(Session session,Reader r,Integer chunk) throws InterruptedException {
    List<Item> list = r.read(chunk);

    if(list.isEmpty()){
        return;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        Item j = list.get(i);
        session.save(j);
    }

    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(2);
    recursive(session,r,chunk);

}
```

I don't know why you have to sleep for 2 mins.